# Square integrable integral by Brownian motion is martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $f \in C_b^2(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R})$. Then my lecturer said that for a Brownian motion $B_t$
\begin{align}
X_t = \int_0^t f(s, B_s) \, dB_s
\end{align}
is a martingale, which should follow from the integral being square integrable, but I can't how to derive this from Ito's formula.

Comment: A sufficient condition for $X_t$ to be a martingale is that $\mathsf{E}\int_0^t [f(s,B_s)]^2\, ds<\infty$ for all $t$, which holds if $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @d.k.o. Do you know the lemma where this follows from?

Comment: Sure. Look at Corollary 3.2.6 [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=VgQDWyihxKYC&pg=PA162&dq=oksendal+stochastic+differential+equations+Corollary3.2.6&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjpPWt6czmAhWPUMAKHeN6AS8Q6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=corollary%203.2.6&f=false). The definition of $\mathcal{V}$ is on page 25.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition @d.k.o. provided in the comments implies that $E[\int_s^t f(u,B_u)dB_u | \mathscr F_s]=0.$
Then, using the linearity property of the integral, we have
$$E[X_t |\mathscr F_s]=E[X_s |\mathscr F_s]+E[\int_s^t f(u,B_u)dB_u | \mathscr F_s]=X_s.$$