# Compute $\tilde{E}\left(B_t - \int_0^t B_s \,ds\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, brownian-motion, martingales

We have that $B$ is a Standard Brownian Motion with $B_0 = 0$ under the prob. measure $P$ and $\tilde{B} = B_t - \int_0^t B_s ds$ for $t\in [0,T]$, $T>0$. I want to calculate
$$
 \tilde{E}\left(B_t - \int_0^t B_s \,ds\right)
$$
where $\tilde{E}$ is the expectation under the probability measure given by Girsanov Theorem... My question is: Since $\tilde{B}$ is a SBM under $\tilde{P}$, is it not zero? Otherwise, how could I do it explicitly?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider process $X_t = B_t - \int B_s ds$, show that this process is gaussian. Then integrate it using Girsanov measure.

Comment: If $\bar B$ is a standard BM under $\bar P$, then $E_{\bar P} [\bar B_t]=0.$

Comment: @onespace Is this last part of integrating using Girsanov where I'm struggling a bit

Comment: @UBM Yeah, I know that it must be zero indeed haha but I think this exercise is written to check that this is true... so they are asking to calculate it explicitly

Comment: @openspace One question: is it true that $E(Z(B_t-B_s) = E(Z) E(B_t-B_s)$? I think it's the state I need

Comment: What does $Z$ mean in your notation?

Comment: @onespace Sorry, the derivative of radon nikodym which defines $\tilde{P}$ in girsanov's theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given
$$\bar B_t = B_t - \int_0^t B_s ds, \tag{1}$$
the corresponding Radon–Nikodym density process of $Q$ with respect to $P$ is
$$\rho_t:=\left. \frac{dQ}{dP} \right|_{\mathcal F_t}=e^{\int_0^t B_s dB_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t B_s^2ds}, \quad 0 \leq t \leq T,$$
which solves the SDE
$$ \rho_t = \rho_t B_t dB_t, \quad \rho_0 = 1. \tag{2}$$
Now, apply the integration by parts formula (Ito product rule) using (1) and (2) to show that $d(\bar B_t \rho_t)=A_t \cdot dB_t$ (for some process $A$). This means that we don't have a drift in the SDE of $B_t \rho_t.$ Thus, $\{B_t \rho_t, 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ is a $P$-local martingale. Then check that $E_P[\int_0^t A^2_s ds] < \infty$ to conclude that $\{B_t \rho_t, 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ is indeed a $P$-martingale. Therefore,
$$E_Q[\bar B_t] = E_P[\bar B_t \rho_t]= E_P[\bar B_0 \rho_0]=E_P[\bar B_0]=E_P[B_0]=0.$$

Comment: I don't understand why the squared integrbaility of A shows that this is a martingale with respect to $\tilde{P} $ :(

Comment: Why do you say $\bar P$? It's martingale with respect to $P.$

Comment: The biggest space for what the Ito integral is defined is the class of adapted process $h$ such that $\int_0^t h^2_u du < \infty.$ The process $I_t:=\{\int_0^t h_udB_u, 0 \leq t \leq T\}$ is a local martingale. If we restrict the class of integrands $h$ to $\{h \text{ adapted such that } E \int_0^t h^2_u du < \infty, \}$ then the process I is a martingale. You will find this in every book where the Ito integral is defined.

Comment: This question may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952224/square-integrable-integral-by-brownian-motion-is-martingale/3952366#3952366

Comment: Now is clear! Thank you very much